# Looking for No Cost Hospitality WiFi Solution

Tags: gratis, networking, network-administration

My company provides Internet access to apartment buildings.

New customers connect to our APs and are redirected to our website where they can purchase service. There are multiple plans available with varying bandwidths.

On sign up, the MAC address of their device is added to a RADIUS server as username. Other information, including bandwidth, is also added.

When a device connects to our network, Nomadix checks our RADIUS server with the MAC address of the device. If authenticated, the RADIUS server returns the bandwidth and time-out (among other things) and Nomadix allows Internet access at the returned bandwidth. After time-out, the device is re-authenticated. This is all transparent to the user.

If not authenticated, the user is redirected to a webpage where they can either purchase service, or authenticate their device with an activation code.

Can anyone advise on a low or no cost alternative to Nomadix for this?

Something that runs on Linux with a robust API would be ideal.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for hardware? Or looking for software to run on your routers? If yes, what routers do you have?

Comment: Also, please remove "Nomadix" from the title, write a title that describes your needs only.

Comment: Ideally something I can install on a Lanner FW-7525C Network Security Appliance.